# SSD on OSX Mountain Lion says it's almost full but isn't

Tags: macos, ssd

So, first things first, my **mac is a hackintosh** so my issue may be some weird issue due to that. However, I was wondering if what I'm experiencing is signs of **ssd failure**. I have a 128gb ssd in the rig for the os, applications and active projects. **Over the past 2 months** the drive has been **slowly losing free space**. I first chalked it up to filling it with projects but all of a sudden it has 100gb used so I check how big my projects and applications are and they are 30gb. I know the os isn't 70gb so I was wondering **if this may be a sign of a failing ssd** or if it may be something else.

Comment: It could be any of a number of things.  For instance, if you don't reboot often, memory tends to get cluttered and the amount of swap storage (in /var/vm/*) increases.  I've seen this swell to more than 20GB before in extreme cases (Safari/Flash/etc to blame), but not 70GB.  In general, the OS+standard apps is around 20-25GB.

Comment: Is Time Machine enabled? Are you taking backups to an external drive? If Time Machine is active but you don't make any backups it can fill the local hard disk with local backups that never get cleared down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your answers. It turns out the majority of the usage was coming from **/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Common/Media Cache Files**(several websites explained this folder can easily sneak its way up to 30gb) which had an Alias setup by another user. The alias was pointing to the other 1tb hard drive but for some reason the disc utility thought the space was still being used on the ssd. I've fixed the issue and put up a symlink instead and now everything is behaving as it should.

Answer (score 0):

TRIM isn't enabled on non-Apple OEM SSDs in OSX.  Perhaps garbage collection is not happening.  You can find a lot of sites that explain how to enable TRIM in OSX.  I haven't provided a link as they are plentiful and you may wish to use a site you're more comfortable with.  Use keywords: "enable trim support OSX terminal"

This [link](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/macbook-pro-ssd-trim,3538.html) explains it but you should not need the freeware tool that the article mentions.  You can enable it from terminal with a few commands.

Comment: Thank you BHall. I've discovered the issue of (at least most of) the unexplained space. It was Adobe's media cache files. I will look into this though and make sure that it is enabled.